How do parse an output of a variable in a batch script?
I am trying to run the following command:
for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%i in (`mlcmd -cshost ***HOST*** -csport 2020 -csappname default -csuser ***UN*** -cspassword ***PW*** -scshost ***HOST*** -scsport 4057 -timeout 60 -getappstatus TServer_CCM_Lab`) do (
  
set response=%%i
)

@echo=%response%

Response: 
TServer_CCM_Lab
Application with DBID 740 has status "APP_STATUS_RUNNING", runmode "PRIMARY" 

How do I parse the response and set APP_STATUS_RUNNING and PRIMARY to variables?
Thanks for your help!

Does this have to be batch scripting? Batch scripting is notoriously difficult to do even basic tasks like this. Can it be Powershell instead? Powershell has shipped with every version of Windows for the past 15 years (albeit different versions)
